# Left and right toggle not showing for navigation

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to replicate the left and right toggle shown on this website:
http://www.alexanderinteractive.com/company/josh

I want to apply this navigation on my site, but can't get the images to show up.

Here's my Code:

```css
       #toggle {
         position: absolute;
         right: 30px;
         top: 30px;
         width: 104px;
         z-index: 2;
       }
       #toggle a.prev {
         background-image: url(http://www.onvia.com/sites/default/files/icon_arrow_left_150x150.png);
       }
       #toggle a.prev {
         margin-right: 20px;
       }
       #toggle a.next {
         background-image: url(http://www.onvia.com/sites/default/files/icon_arrow_right_150x150.png);
       }
       .clear:before,
       .clear:after {
         content: "\0020";
         display: block;
         height: 0;
         overflow: hidden;
       }
```

```html
<div id="toggle" class="clear">
  <a href="http://www.apple.com" class="prev">Previous</a>
  <a href="http://www.microsoft.com" class="next">Next</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

all you need to do is add

```
#toggle a {
text-indent: -9999px;
background-size: cover;
width: 35px;
height: 35px;
display: inline-block;
}
```

The `text-indent` removes the text; the parent element is `position: absolute;`, so you need to set the `height` and `width` for the element, and the `background-size: cover;` makes the background image as large as the containing element allows.
[Here is the jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cr5dnsLt/)

Comment: Can you show me on the jsfiddle? I tried adding that, but I'm still not seeing the toggle images

Comment: I just added the new styles on your existing css and it worked, here is the link http://jsfiddle.net/cr5dnsLt/